# Error al sincronizar repositorio remoto en GitHub desde Visual Studio

Tags: github

Necesito ayuda, `GitHub` no me había generado problema antes, pero quiero sincronizar un repositorio remoto y me aparece este error al momento de insertar los cambios.

> Error al insertar en el repositorio remoto. Consulte la ventana Resultados para obtener más detalles.

Y en la ventana de Resultados aparece esto:

> Repositorios de apertura:
>   C:\Users\esme_\Source\Repos\SistemaIntegralControl
>   Se produjo un error al insertar en el repositorio remoto: El código de estado de la respuesta no indica un resultado correcto: 403 (Forbidden).

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucionar esto?

Comment: Y en la ventana `Resultados` ¿Qué tipo de problemas o mensajes aparecen?

Comment: Además de agregar esa información relevante (cómo se describe en [ask]), por favor no agregues etiquetas que no están relacionadas a tu pregunta

Comment: Si muchas gracias. Incluí en mi pregunta lo que me aparece en la ventana de resultados, ojala pueda resolver esto pronto.

Comment: Estas usando la url con https?
 Echa un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed) a ver si te da una pista

Comment: De hecho efectué la función de cambiar la URL pero eso no resolvió nada.

Comment: Eso sucede por que no forkeaste el proyecto antes de intentar hacer el commit, recuerda, debes forkearlo en la github, y después clonar desde tu fork para que eso no te pase.

Comment: Ese mensaje fue te aparece porque no tienes permiso para hacer un pull al repositorio